# Can I submit to TestFlight for a beta iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode, testflight, beta, ios16

I would like to TestFlight an app updated for iOS 16 b3 even though iOS 16 is not public yet, however there is a public beta for iOS 16 . The app's deployment target is iOS 15. Is this possible? The updated code is properly handled for each OS version. I cannot find any references for this scenario online thus asking here. Any feedback is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try it, but probably your upload will be rejected

Answer (score 0):

Give it a try, I think it will work!
by using the "Xcode 14 beta", and update your iPhone to the "iOS16 beta".